# Error opening New Searcher. Core is missing: `Sitecore_Analytics_Index`

Tags: solr

Our Sitecore Solr has issues with the Sitecore analytics index and the error message is :

```
Error opening New Searcher. Core is missing.
```

We tried to look in to the error but could not gather much information on why this is happening.

This is a production environment and we need to make sure that adding the Solr core again with same index files helps before going through deploying process.

The error is as follows:

```
null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'sitecore_analytics_index' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:884)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.init(HttpSolrCall.java:247)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:412)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:815)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:658)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:637)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:381)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:148)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1657)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1769)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initSearcher(SolrCore.java:911)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:788)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: codec header mismatch: actual header=423661802 vs expected header=1071082519 (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="xxx/solr/data/sitecore_analytics_index_sec/data/index.20180908031501818/_1f8x.cfs") [slice=_1f8x.fnm]))
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkHeader(CodecUtil.java:197)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkIndexHeader(CodecUtil.java:256)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.read(Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.java:115)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.readFieldInfos(IndexWriter.java:908)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getFieldNumberMap(IndexWriter.java:924)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:854)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.(SolrIndexWriter.java:78)
    at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:65)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:273)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1626)
    ... 12 more
    Suppressed: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: codec footer mismatch (file truncated?): actual footer=0 vs expected footer=-1071082520 (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="xxx/solr/data/sitecore_analytics_index_sec/data/index.20180908031501818/_1f8x.cfs") [slice=_1f8x.fnm]))
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.validateFooter(CodecUtil.java:416)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkFooter(CodecUtil.java:331)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkFooter(CodecUtil.java:379)
        at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.read(Lucene50FieldInfosFormat.java:164)
        ... 20 more
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98744/discussion-on-question-by-yenugudhati-mahesh-varma-error-opening-new-searcher-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the feedback received from @Haneen Daoud, I have looked at my corrupted cores in slave Solr. I see all the folders for the corrupted cores are present and understood from the logs that one of the segments of index is corrupted because of 100% memory utilization happened which is because of few error logs.

I see conf, data folders and core.properties text file in the /var/Solr/data/Sitecore_analytics_index core. Data folder under path /var/Solr/data/Sitecore_analytics_index has the index folder and index.properties, replication.properties text files. I have deleted this data folder and restarted solr and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

would you verify that the core exists In the apache-solr\server\solr folder, do you see a sitecore_analytics_index folder? if not you can use the following instructions to add the new index:

1. Duplicate master folder index in apache-solr\server\solr dircetory
2. Rename the copied folder into "sitecore_analytics_index" and delete "data" folder and core.properties files from the new folder
3. Navigate to solr "core Admin" and add new core for "Sitecore_analytics_index"

Comment: Hi Haneen, Yes I can see the index folder. And the data folder has the multiple index files with different time stamps like index.20190719143039572. When we used lucene-core library and used java command "java -cp lucene-core-2.9.3.jar -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex" it returned "Can't read segments file. Since this proves that core is corrupted, we can replace the old index folder with the new one from master with the above mentioned steps, thank you! Please let us know the extra care that should be taken if any like stopping solr, config related changes etc.,